# How do we initialize SparkSession and SparkContext in python 3.6?

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

So, I am trying to initialize SparkSession and SparkContext in python 3.6 using the following code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark import SparkContext  

#Create a Spark Session
SpSession = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .master("local[2]") \
    .appName("V2 Maestros") \
    .config("spark.executor.memory", "1g") \
    .config("spark.cores.max","2") \
    .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "file:///c:/temp/spark-warehouse")\
    .getOrCreate()
```

I get the following error everytime I try to do this:

```
module 'pyspark' has no attribute 'heapq3'
```

Please let me know where I am mistaken. I am pretty new to spark.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is an issue with python 3.6. please refer [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19019). I recommend you to user older version of python now. Once the issue is fixed and tested, you can start using with python 3.6